# How to manage the layout of React Router Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

All:

I am pretty new to React Router, when I follow [this great tutorial](https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-react-router-53094349669#.nx3dsfm8r), there is one thing I can not find out, which is:

How can I adjust the layout to decide which area in the window can be proper rendered, the component structure talked in that tutorial is more like logic structure for content but not too much related UI layout/style.

Could anyone show me a simple example about how to apply style to according component to make sure they are in right place?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Just add classes around your views? `<div className="some-layout">{this.props.children}</div>`

Comment: @azium Thanks, I guess I misunderstand how Router works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your components should know how to do this. Use parent components to control the placement of their children. For example, a common pattern that I use for my apps is similar to:

```
var Nav = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      {'I am the Nav bar'}
    );
  }
});

var RightContent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      {'I am Right Content'}
    );
  }
});

var LeftContent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      {'I am Left Content'}
    );
  }
});

import {Col, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
var Content = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <LeftContent />
        </Col>
        <Col md={6}>
          <RightContent />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

You can see here that each component is fully responsible for placing its children. Generally it is good practice to have parent components that do layout and then children components that actually have content.

In terms of per-component styling, you can apply CSS directly at the component layer (discussion of which is outside the scope of this question), or you can continue to use your normal global CSS stylesheets - just think of each component as a `div` that may or may not be on the page.

Comment: Thanks, so the way React Router works is just simply using component assigned to it, and replace with that component's HTML in place when that Route applied? Then it is enough to just take care what that component's look. There is no something like `ui-view` in Angular to specify where to render

Comment: React Router simply describes which component should render your path. That component may or may not use additional sub-components to help it render. Some of those sub-components might be passed to it via React Router, thus the use of `this.props.children`. React renders from the bottom up: all child components' renders will be called and resolved before the parent component's render.